# how to display values on chart graph using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, bar-chart

I need to display points values in chart graph 
when I tried the result was

[image]

But I want it like

[image]

My code is

```
SqlCommand territorycommand = new SqlCommand("select Terriotry,TotalAcheivmentVol,Forecast from ForecastTotal where Year = '" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "' and Terriotry = '" + territory + "' and month = '"+Month+"'", conn);
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        mydatareader = territorycommand.ExecuteReader();
                        while (mydatareader.Read())
                        {
                            chart1.Series["TotalAchievment"].Points.AddXY(mydatareader.GetString(0), mydatareader.GetInt32(1));
                            chart1.Series["Forecast"].Points.AddY(mydatareader.GetInt32(2));
                            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
                            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    conn.Close();
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Have you tried `chart1.Series["TotalAchievment"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true` ?

Comment: thx it's worked ^_^ .. put ur answer plz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can show series value in label as:

```
chart1.Series["TotalAchievment"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true
chart1.Series["Forecast"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true
```

Comment: is the same in line graph ?

Comment: yup! there is something called smart labels as well. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670580/how-to-make-series-labels-to-show-without-overlapping-each-other-asp-net-4-0