# c# How to show Chart Y value Label using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, charts

[image]
This one Linq code I have in  FormLoad event:

```
ShowChartReport();

            chart1.Series.Clear();

            var series = chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
            series.XValueMember = "ProduktId";
            series.YValueMembers = "TolatlSold"; 
            series.Name = "Products";
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

And then this following methode for chart upploading

```
private void ShowChartReport()
        {
            using (CoffeEntities db = new CoffeEntities())
            {
                var result = (from pr in db.SaleDetails
                              group pr by pr.Product.Description into g
                              select new
                              {
                                  ProduktId = g.Key,
                                  TolatlSold = g.Count()


                              }).ToList();
                chart1.DataSource = result;  
                chart1.DataBind();
                chart1.Show();

            }
        }
```

I tried even like this inside ShowChartReport()

```
chart1.Series["ProduktId"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
chart1.Series["TolatlSold"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

But stil I can not see those Y value Label in every chart element.

It's exactly like this question [how to display values on chart graph using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784648/how-to-display-values-on-chart-graph-using-c-sharp) 
 I want but I'am using Linq and confusing me How to do...  I  would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: `chart1.Series["ProduktId"]` But your series is called `Series1` or maybe `Products` ! ? I also would recommend binding to one series's Points, not the whole chart. Now, what is the result? Are the data shown and no labels displayed or only some? Can you add a screenshot?  The chart is a column chart? does it look right otherwise? Are both datatypes numbers?

Comment: @TaW Thank you for your response. I have added now a picture how it's looks like right now and How I want to be look like

Comment: OK. But did you also try to use the correct series name as I told you: `chart1.Series["Products"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;` ??

Comment: @TaW no, but when I did now it's working, and Thank you so much!  But they shows exactly over the Y axel line and different to se them. How can I move then litle to thr right or to the left?

Comment: You can't do that really. At least not easily. You may consider turning the majorgridlines either off or use a lighter color for them.

Comment: @TaW I did series.CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left"; now they are on the left side. Thank you again